# Cassandra limit clause for timestamp(timeuuid)

Tags: cassandra, timeuuid

I have a cassandra table structure as follows

```
create table demo (user_id text , comment_id text , timestamp timeuuid , PRIMARY KEY (user_id , comment_id , timestamp))
```

Now in the UI I want pagination such that on the click of next button , I should get the value from 10 to 20 then 20 to 30 and so on.

I know we cant initiate a query in cassandra as

```
select * from demo limit 10,20
```

So if I create a query as

```
select * from demo where timestamp = 'sometimestampvalue' limit 10;
```

This will give 10 values from  '`sometimestampvalue`'  till next 10 values.

Then store the last row timestamp  value in a variable (say X) and then initiate the next query as

```
select * from demo where timestamp = 'X' limit 10;
```

And so On, will this work  ? or something better can be done as I'm ready to change the structure of table also with counter columns added as basically I should be able to do pagination based on any column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer:
[Cassandra Limit 10,20 clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025490/cassandra-limit-10-20-clause?rq=1)

Basically you will have to handle it in your app code. Your suggestion looks like it will work, with a little tweaking.

Comment: Hi Alec, thanks for the answer , basically I need this for pagination in UI , but I was going though the cassandra doc , I guess they have paging API that serves the purpose without having to worry about what I had proposed in the question. Please suggest if I'm wrong ! and just for the sake of it if you could point out in the answer exactly what tweaking is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is more easily done in the driver where you can set the **fetch size**.  For example, in Java:

```
cluster.getConfiguration().getQueryOptions().setFetchSize(10);
```

See DataStax [Java Driver for Apache Cassandra, Features, Paging](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.1.8/features/paging/)